# Como obter o número de semanas num intervalo de datas em C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Gostaria de saber como saber o número de semanas num determinado intervalo de datas em C#.

Comment: Defina semana. Você quer saber quantas segundas (ou outro dia) tem entre uma data e outra? Ou apenas a quantidade de dias dividida por 7?

Answer (score 3):

Existem várias formas, dependendo do que você estiver considerando como sendo uma semana.

**Semanas inteiras do calendário**

Considerando apenas semanas inteiras do calendário, ou seja, somente são contabilizadas semanas do calendário que estiverem totalmente inseridas no intervalo:

```
public static int SemanasInteirasDoCalendario(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
{
    if (d2 < d1) throw new ArgumentException(
        "'d1' precisa ser menor ou igual que 'd2'");
    return ((d2 - d1).Days + 1
        - ((int)d1.DayOfWeek > 0 ? 6 - (int)d1.DayOfWeek : 0)
        - ((int)d2.DayOfWeek < 6 ? (int)d2.DayOfWeek : 0)) / 7;
}
```

**Semanas parciais do calendário**

Considera qualquer semana do calendário, em que pelo menos um dia desta semana está dentro do intervalo:

```
public static int SemanasParciaisDoCalendario(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
{
    return SemanasInteirasDoCalendario(d1, d2)
        + ((int)d1.DayOfWeek > 0 ? 1 : 0)
        + ((int)d2.DayOfWeek < 6
            && d1.Date.AddDays(-(int)d1.DayOfWeek) != d2.Date.AddDays(-(int)d2.DayOfWeek)
            ? 1 : 0);
}
```

**Semanas inteiras**

Considera intervalos inteiros de 7 dias seguidos que estejam dentro do intervalo de datas passadas:

```
public static int SemanasInteiras(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
{
    if (d2 < d1) throw new ArgumentException(
        "'d1' precisa ser menor ou igual que 'd2'");
    return ((d2 - d1).Days + 1) / 7;
}
```

**Semanas parciais**

Considera intervalos de 7 dias em que pelo menos um dos dias aparece dentro do intervalo de datas:

```
public static int SemanasParciais(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
{
    if (d2 < d1) throw new ArgumentException(
        "'d1' precisa ser menor ou igual que 'd2'");
    var days = (d2 - d1).Days + 1;
    return days / 7 + Math.Sign(days % 7);
}
```

**Semanas inteiras de trabalho**

Considera apenas semanas inteiras de trabalho (de segunda até sexta) que estão inseridas dentro do intervalo passado:

```
public static int SemanasInteirasDeTrabalho(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
{
    if (d2 < d1) throw new ArgumentException(
        "'d1' precisa ser menor ou igual que 'd2'");
    return ((d2 - d1).Days + 1
        - ((int)d1.DayOfWeek > 1 ? 6 - (int)d1.DayOfWeek : -(int)d1.DayOfWeek)
        - ((int)d2.DayOfWeek < 5 ? (int)d2.DayOfWeek : (int)d2.DayOfWeek - 6)) / 7;
}
```

**Semanas parciais de trabalho**

Considera qualquer semana de trabalho (segunda até sexta) em que pelo menos um dos dias está dentro do intervalo de datas passado:

```
public static int SemanasParciaisDeTrabalho(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
{
    return SemanasInteirasDeTrabalho(d1, d2)
        + ((int)d1.DayOfWeek > 1 && (int)d1.DayOfWeek < 6 ? 1 : 0)
        + ((int)d2.DayOfWeek < 5 && (int)d2.DayOfWeek > 0
            && d1.Date.AddDays(-(int)d1.DayOfWeek) != d2.Date.AddDays(-(int)d2.DayOfWeek)
            ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Poderia tentar desta forma:

```
public int NumeroDeSemanas(DateTime dataInicial, DateTime dataFinal)
{
   TimeSpan Span = dataFinal.Subtract(dataInicial);

   //Testa se a diferença é menor ou igual a 7 (número de dias em uma semana)
   if (Span.Days <= 7)
   {
      if (dataInicial.DayOfWeek > dataFinal.DayOfWeek)
      {
         return 2;
      }

      return 1;
   }

   int Dias = Span.Days - 7 + (int)dataInicial.DayOfWeek;
   int SemanasCount = 1;
   int DiasCount = 0;

   for (SemanasCount = 1; DiasCount < Dias; SemanasCount++)
   {
      DiasCount += 7;
   }

   return SemanasCount;
}
```

Como parâmetro para este método você passa a data inicial e a data final, e o método retorna o número de semanas.

Answer (score 1):

Tente utilizar isso, mais simples:

```
    public int totalSemanas(DateTime dataInicial, DateTime dataFim)
    {
        return (dataFim - dataInicial).Days / 7;
    }
```

Comment: é mais simples, porém ao meu ver, incorreto. Pelo seu método, do dia 16/02/2014 até 25/02/2014, é contabilizado apenas uma semana. Sendo que os dias 23, 24 e 25 já fazem parte da segunda semana, que não foi contabilizada pelo teu algoritmo.

Comment: Depende do ponto de vista e da necessidade também.
Qualquer coisa faz um Math.Round() pra que arredonde pra cima.

Mas, bem levantado a sua colocação.

Answer (score 0):

Tente este metodo:

```
public int totalSemanas(DateTime dataInicial, DateTime dataFim)
{
    return (int)Math.Ceiling(((dataFim- dataInicial).TotalDays + 1) / 7d);
}
```

Ou este:

```
public int GetCalendarWeeks(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    return (endDate.GetBeginningOfWeek().Subtract(startDate.GetBeginningOfWeek()).Days / 7) + 1;
}

public static DateTime GetBeginningOfWeek(this DateTime date)
{
    var dayOfWeekOffSet = date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ? 6 : ((int)date.DayOfWeek) - 1;
    return date.AddDays(-1 * dayOfWeekOffSet).Date;
}

public static DateTime GetEndOfWeek(this DateTime date)
{
    var dayOfWeekOffSet = date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ? 0 : 7 - ((int)date.DayOfWeek);
    return date.AddDays(dayOfWeekOffSet).Date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) existe a função `dateDiff` que te auxilia nisso. E para utilizar no c#, basta adicionar a referência `"Microsoft.VisualBasic"` no seu projeto, e incluir o `namespace` na sua classe:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
```

Segue exemplo de código:

```
        DateTime x = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-31);
        DateTime y = DateTime.Today;

        long l = DateAndTime.DateDiff(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, x, y);
        long ll = DateAndTime.DateDiff(DateInterval.Weekday, x, y);
```